# Query multiple tables but getting only the result from one table without duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Here is an example to explain what I need:

I have 3 tables:

```
 contact: { id, invoices, name } // a contact can have several invoices
 invoice: { id, contact, lines, comment } // an invoice can have several lines but only one contact
 line: { id, invoice, designation } // a line can have only one invoice
```

If a user search an invoice, a want to query the comment, designation and name fields and getting only the invoice that match.

So I've done this:

```
SELECT 
  invoice.id AS id, 
  invoice.contact AS contact, 
  invoice.comment AS comment, 
FROM invoice 
  LEFT JOIN contact ON invoice.contact = contact.id 
  LEFT JOIN line ON line.invoice = invoice.id
WHERE (
  contact.name LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%' OR 
  invoice.comment LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%' OR 
  line.designation LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%'
)
```

This work except that if an invoice has several lines which match the search term, I will get several times the same invoice.

So my question is: is there a way to get only once an invoice even if the search term is find in several related records ?

Also, is there a way to get only the fields of the invoice without using ALIAS (I don't care about the tables contact and line except for the search) ?

If you know a better way to do that, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT invoice.*
FROM invoice 
  LEFT JOIN contact ON invoice.contact = contact.id 
  LEFT JOIN line ON line.invoice = invoice.id
WHERE (
  contact.name LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%' OR 
  invoice.comment LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%' OR 
  line.designation LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can do this by adding a subquery to the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT invoice.id AS id, invoice.contact AS contact, invoice.comment AS comment, 
FROM invoice LEFT JOIN
     contact
     ON invoice.contact = contact.id 
WHERE contact.name LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%' OR 
      invoice.comment LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%' OR
      invoice.id in (select line.invoice
                     from line
                     where line.designation LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%')
```

You can also structure this in the FROM clause using a subquery:

```
SELECT invoice.id AS id, invoice.contact AS contact, invoice.comment AS comment, 
FROM invoice LEFT JOIN
     contact
     ON invoice.contact = contact.id left join
     (select distinct line.invoice
      from line
      where line.designation LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%'
     ) line
     on line.invoice = invoice.id
WHERE contact.name LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%' OR 
      invoice.comment LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%' OR
      line.invoice is not null
```

In this construction, you need the distinct keyword to prevent duplicate lines, if more than one line has the search term.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I wasn't aware of the subquery thing. The problem with this is that in my case, it take 100s to make the query using a subquery instead of 0.5s using a simple left join.

Comment: No comment on the ability of SQL compilers to come up with the best execution plan.  The two queries are identical in the sense that they produce the same results.  However, optimizers are notoriously bad at dealing with join constructs using IN and NOT IN.

Answer (score 0):

Will DISTINCT work?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  i.id, 
  i.contact, 
  i.comment, 
FROM invoice AS i
  LEFT JOIN contact ON i.contact = contact.id 
  LEFT JOIN line ON line.invoice = i.id
WHERE (
  contact.name LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%' OR 
  i.comment LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%' OR 
  line.designation LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%'
)
```